# "[Error] request for member in something not a structure or union"

Tags: dev-c++

Galera, eu to tentando fazer uma struct que recebe informações do usuário e apos isso exiba as informações. Mas está apresentando esse erro quando vou compilar '[Error] request for member in something not a structure or union".

Segue o Código...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct funcionario
{
    char nome[40];
    char cargo[40];
    int cpf[11];
};

cad_func[2];


int main(void) {

    int i;

    printf("INSIRA SEUS DADOS.\n\n\n");

    for(i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        printf("nome: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(cad_func[i].nome);

        printf("cargo: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(cad_func[i].cargo);

        printf("cpf: ");
        scanf("%d", &cad_func[i].cpf);


    }

    printf("Dados dos funcionarios:\n\n");

    for(i=0; i<2; i++){
        printf("Nome: %s", cad_func[i].nome);
        printf("Cargo: %s", cad_func[i].cargo);
        printf("Nome: %d", cad_func[i].cpf);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Obrigado!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse erro está ocorrendo, pois você não informou o tipo da variável `cad_func[2]`.

Para corrigir isso, basta informar o tipo, que é a `struct funcionario`:

```
struct funcionario cad_func[2];
```

Com isso seu programa já passa a compilar e executar.